# stuck on the error. Invalid hook call. Everything looks good

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So I am trying to make a function that get the login infos to my API.
Have tried everything. But its keep stopping the line of the useSate (where there is the red arrow).
So it looks the useState doesn't want to work for no reason because the log just before works as you can see on the error screenshot.
Notice that the previous exported function works perfectly.
And I dont have mismatching versions of react.

Any ideas ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your screenshots. But the rule is, you shouldn't use hooks inside regular functions:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions

Comment: Please provide full code with `queryLogin`, since you are using hooks inside it. Are `useQueryLogin` and `queryLogin` the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you have `useFindAllBarAround` as your ***Custom hook*** starting with the word ***use***, could you also do the same with `queryLogin`?